# cant get tax value even putting in formula

Tags: c, cs50

Hi I'm very new in c programming, I realized my tax is 0 even I putting in formula, anyone can help to explain why? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uvEg.jpg)

Comment: Please don’t post code as an image. You wrote it as text so include it as text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions, and copy-paste code (all text really) as actual text into your questions.

Comment: Use proper indentation in your code and the problem should then be obvious. The tax is only calculated for pay <= 300 and you are entering pay greater than that.

Comment: The tax calculation you have in the code doesn't match the stated calculations in the comment. I suggest you sit down with pen and paper and think about the tax calculation a bit more.

Comment: The program is also not addressing everything in the comments/description.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] as text. ideally formatted als code according to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: On a minor note, instead or recalculating `h * r` in the overtime scenario, just add the overtime pay to the existing value of `pay`.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in your image, the gross pay is $498 and $570 right? If you look at your if-statement at line 29, the gross pay will need to be less than or equal to 300 to return true. In your case, this returns false and your tax calculation is never run.

Comment: Thanks for the reminding brother 

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect logic.

```
//Tax
if (pay <=300)
tax = ( pay * 0.15);
```

Try---

```
if(pay > 450)
    tax = (pay - 450)*0.25+75;
else if(pay > 300)
    tax = (pay - 300)*0.2+45;
else
    tax = pay*0.15;
```

Comment: In the `if(pay > 300)` case your calculation could turn negative. It also doesn't really follow the logic set out in the comment.